# Proper architecture of the android app (1 MainActivity and several Fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I’m creating right now an android app with 1 MainActivity and several Fragments. It is advised to use an interface from Fragment which methods are overridden in MainActivity (http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/). But if I put all the logic of every Fragment inside of MainActivity, MainActivity will be very big with hundreds lines of code. Is it how it has to be? I doubt. What will you recommend?

Comment: The approach described in the article solves the problem of establishing the means of communication between your Fragments and the Activity, so you don't have to put Fragment logic into the Activity, only the code related to the communication between the components.

Comment: You don't put logic from fragments inside your Main activity. You only add interfaces. It's how your Activity communicates with your Fragment. For example you send some value from Activity to fragment, fragment applies some logic to it and returns a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are mainly use to communicate between Activity and Fragment. So the main business logic of Fragment will be staying in fragment. You are just adding one function to communicate between fragment and Activity. So that wont be increasing the size of activity as such.